# Replicate Canvas resize in a Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

There's any way to replicate this scale behavior in a `div` ?

Here's an example of the behavior I wanted to reproduce within the `div`. I already have the movement part, and I just wanted to know about the resizing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    #wrapper {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      width: 578px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    #buttonWrapper {
      position: absolute;
      width: 30px;
      top: 2px;
      right: 2px;
    }
    
    input[type="button"] {
      padding: 5px;
      width: 30px;
      margin: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function draw(scale, translatePos) {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      // clear canvas
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      context.save();
      context.translate(translatePos.x, translatePos.y);
      context.scale(scale, scale);
      context.beginPath(); // begin custom shape
      context.moveTo(-119, -20);
      context.bezierCurveTo(-159, 0, -159, 50, -59, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(-39, 80, 31, 80, 51, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(131, 50, 131, 20, 101, 0);
      context.bezierCurveTo(141, -60, 81, -70, 51, -50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(31, -95, -39, -80, -39, -50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(-89, -95, -139, -80, -119, -20);
      context.closePath(); // complete custom shape
      var grd = context.createLinearGradient(-59, -100, 81, 100);
      grd.addColorStop(0, "#8ED6FF"); // light blue
      grd.addColorStop(1, "#004CB3"); // dark blue
      context.fillStyle = grd;
      context.fill();

      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = "#0000ff";
      context.stroke();
      context.restore();
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

      var translatePos = {
        x: canvas.width / 2,
        y: canvas.height / 2
      };

      var scale = 1.0;
      var scaleMultiplier = 0.8;
      var startDragOffset = {};
      var mouseDown = false;

      // add button event listeners
      document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
        scale /= scaleMultiplier;
        draw(scale, translatePos);
      }, false);

      document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function() {
        scale *= scaleMultiplier;
        draw(scale, translatePos);
      }, false);

      // add event listeners to handle screen drag
      canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
        mouseDown = true;
        startDragOffset.x = evt.clientX - translatePos.x;
        startDragOffset.y = evt.clientY - translatePos.y;
      });

      canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
        mouseDown = false;
      });

      canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
        mouseDown = false;
      });

      canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
        mouseDown = false;
      });

      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
        if (mouseDown) {
          translatePos.x = evt.clientX - startDragOffset.x;
          translatePos.y = evt.clientY - startDragOffset.y;
          draw(scale, translatePos);
        }
      });

      draw(scale, translatePos);
    };



    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $("#wrapper").mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#status').html(e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
      });
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body onmousedown="return false;">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200">
    </canvas>
    <div id="buttonWrapper">
      <input type="button" id="plus" value="+"><input type="button" id="minus" value="-">
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 id="status">
    0, 0
  </h2>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to use css scale, but it resizes the `div` too, I want to modify only the space and the elements inside it.

Comment: _"I tried to use css scale, but it resizes the div too, I want to modify only the space and the elements inside it."_ - well then apply it only to elements inside the div, and not the div itself?